# Worker Thread Implementation to connect SQL Server in Node JS

Tags: node.js, worker-thread

I need to implement Worker thread for an API to execute in concurrent way,
API work is pull the data from SQL server,
How to implement worker thread concept to connect SQL server and get the data from Database

Most of Worker thread ref, only have the example without Database operations

Comment: If you are only going to pull data from SQL server, then you don't really need a worker thread. Worker threads are for CPU intensive work. In your case the worker thread will just idle wait for SQL to return data.
_"Worker threads do not help much with I/O-intensive work. The Node.js built-in asynchronous I/O operations are more efficient than Workers can be."_ - [source](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html)

Comment: Thanks for your information, i will check the documentation

Comment: @MitkoPetrov Well, I have read your above comment and now I'm not sure if Worker threads will not affect much in DB operation then would you please let me know, In which kind of requirements this suites well to implement?

Comment: @SachinShah You would use threads when you are actually calculating something, not when you are waiting for another server to respond to request. You could start a worker thread as background task, for example for image/video processing, sorting, in-memory searching, file encoding/decoding/compressing (tasks that could take few seconds to minutes), so your main thread can stay free to serve other incoming requests. If you do such work on main thread, your API will stop accepting client requests, because it will be busy working.

Comment: Okay noted. Thanks for reply and unfortunately I did get a chance to work things which you have mentioned above.  @MitkoPetrov